# How can i back up a hard drive as a mountable drive image (encrypted)

Tags: windows-7, disk-image

I want to back up my HDD so I can wipe it and start fresh. However I want to create an image of it as it is right now that I can mount at any time as another drive.

I want this image to be encrypted.

I am using windows 7/8 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your drive to a VHD, reinstall your fresh windows and then mount the VHD.
(See [[Copying Windows 7 host to VHD](https://superuser.com/questions/317937/copying-windows-7-host-to-vhd)](https://superuser.com/questions/317937/copying-windows-7-host-to-vhd))

Or you can do the same with Vmware convertor to convert it to a VMDK and you can mount that after the re-installation.

I do not know if you can add encryption during this process. (Though you could encrypt the VMDK or VHD file, or you could store it in a truecrypt container or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called Norton Ghost which helps you do a complete backup of your HDD, I'm not sure about the encryption part though!

Answer (score 0):

I use software called [R-Drive Image](http://www.drive-image.com/).  You can create an image which can then be mounted as a drive using the software.  There is an option for it to be password protected but I've never used that option.  It does cost money but there is a 15 day full version trial which works great for just one timers.  I use it all the time when fixing friends computers as a quick backup, then I format and reinstall, then mount and copy data back.